# How to execute Adobe javascript call in Jmeter

Tags: javascript, jmeter, adobe-analytics

I am using the latest Jmeter ver. 3.3 and tried executing Adobe analytic JS call using JSR223 sampler but fails to show up in analytics dashboard.
Can anyone help me, need to trigger analytic call with load test.

Thanks,
A

Comment: Unless you have a selenium sampler, JMeter has no way to execute JS. You should see instead which HTTP call is created as a result of that JS call, and get that into JMeter. If you are in fact dealing with Selenium sampler, then google "run JS from selenium", there's a lot of articles about that

Answer (score 2):

Looking into [Adobe API Explorer](https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/api-explorer) given you have credentials, to wit **API Username** and **Shared Secret** (you can find them at your [Account Information](https://sc.omniture.com/p/suite/1.3/index.html?a=User.GetAccountInfo) page) you should be able to execute necessary SOAP or REST request using JMeter's [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler.

You will also need [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send i.e. `X-WSSE` header, [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header, etc.

See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) article for more information on configuring JMeter for simulating web service requests.